To be logged at an amount
To my mind, log something = record something officially. For example, I might write:


The company has logged more than 90 complaints.


But what about in passive voice? Is it correct to say:


Data on Korea’s waste output in 1980 was unavailable, but it was logged at 31 million tons in 1990 and declined to 19 million in the final year examined.


By it here, I mean Korea's waste output. I added at because it feels right to me, but I'm pretty confused and unsure about how "log" should be used in this situation.

"Logged" is more commonly used for things like complaints or sales which are put in a log (a list of things). But you could use "More than 90 complaints were logged" or "31 million tons were logged" etc. "Was logged at" doesn't sound very good to me, but if you want that construction then "at" as probably the best option. "It was measured at 31 million tons" is good; or I can find examples like "the volume of crops production was recorded at 25.07 million metric tons".

Personally, I'd rather use ...was logged as 31M tons. Note that whereas you could also get away with at in ...was recorded at 31M tons, it's far less idiomatic to use conjunction / preposition at in ...was verified as 31M tons. So for an easy life, stick to as everywhere.
